# Creating Links on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

I've just started using rails yesterday, so this is a kinda noob question

for example, a user is at www.example.com/name
and I want to make several links to www.example.com/name/:id

So I tried something like this:

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
<%= link_to item.name, '/name' :id %>
<% end %>
```

I know, it was a complete guess on how I should write the code, but the restful code sends to a completely wrong link. How should I write this three lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the route helper:

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
    <%= link_to item.name, item_path(item) %>
<% end %>
```

ps: when you have a simple question like this one, take a look at [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/), you'll often find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<%= link_to item.name, item_path(item) %>
```

`item_path` is a URL helper method which spits out the link to show a name.

URL helpers have the general form:

```
{action}_{class}_path({object or object_id})
```

If `{action}_` is omitted, then the default action is assumed (normally show).

Comment: Ok, but now the links are like www.example.com/name.id, cant it be like www.example.com/name/id?